# Activity bot - parallax - moving the robots with sensors - C Programming

Tags: c, parallax, robotics

This is my code for moving an activity bot from its starting point to the ending point.  It detects obstacles on both sides and turns away from them.

I save the sequence of moves in an array so that I can return to the starting point without using any sensors. **(Which is the code after the "//return" comment)

```
#include "simpletools.h"
#include "abdrive.h"
#include "ping.h"

int back[200];
int i = 0;

int main() {  
  int distance;

  int irLeft = 0, irRight = 0;

  low(26);
  low(27);

  while (1) {
    if (ping_cm(8) < 5) {
      break;
    }

    freqout(11, 1, 38000);  
    irLeft = input(10); 

    freqout(1, 1, 38000);                     
    irRight = input(2);

    if (irLeft == irRight == 1) {
      drive_goto(10,10);
      back[i] = 10;
      ++i;
      back[i]= 10;
      ++i;
    }

    if (irLeft == 0) {
      drive_goto(20,10);
      back[i] = 20;
      ++i;
      back[i] = 10;
      ++i;
    }

    if (irRight == 0) {
      drive_goto(10,20);
      back[i]= 10;
      ++i;
      back[i]= 20;
      ++i;
    }
  }    
  drive_goto(51, 0);   // Make a 180 degree turn
  drive_goto(51, 0); 

//return
  while (1) {
    if (i == 0) {
      break;
    }
    drive_goto(back[i], back[--i]);
    --i; 
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

The robot successfully moves to the goal, but it does not move back to the starting point. What can the problem be?

Comment: `if (irLeft == irRight == 1)` does not make sense. Should be `if (irLeft == 1 && irRight == 1)` .

Comment: I do not know what the problem is, but for a known route suggest looking at the *first* move back towards the start. Then the *next* move. That is: find a way to debug the code yourself. I can't even follow the code because of the poor formatting. Get that in order too, and it will inevitably improve your logical approach. (Improved by John Bollinger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have an off-by-one error.  As you move forward, you track in variable `i` the index of the *next available* position in your movement history array.  When you start the trip back, you use the current value of `i` as if it were instead the index of the last value recorded.  On the way back you need to decrement `i` *before* each read, mirroring the behavior on the forward path of incrementing it *after* each write.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It is the actually why my code doesnt work. haha